# How do I search for multiple tag combinations at once?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, tag-search

I would like to search for questions with [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) and [bar](/questions/tagged/bar) OR [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) and [foobar](/questions/tagged/foobar). So written in JavaScript it would look like this:

```
if ((foo && bar) || (foo && foobar)) {}
```

How can I achieve this in search?

**Edit:** I was informed this is currently not possible so I added [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Comment: You can't in the on-site search. Use SEDE or the api.

Comment: @rene I'm not familiar with the SEDE - could you elaborate?

Comment: As an example https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1182571 and the tutorial is here: https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial

Comment: @rene I think that's the answer, and you should post it as such

Answer (score -1):

One way is to do a site-specific search with Google or another search engine. For your example:

> site:meta.stackexchange.com (foo or bar) and (foo or foobar)

Comment: How does this search for tags?